# Jmap for play framework on heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, heap-dump, jmap

I'd like to take heap dumps of a play framework (v2.4.x) deployed on heroku.
I read this [heroku guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues#profiling-memory-use-of-a-java-application) which instructs to prefix the java command with with_jmap. However play has its own start script that executes java and the with_jmap option is ignored.

What's the correct way of configuring jmap on play heroku?
If there's an alternate way of getting heap dumps on heroku other than jmap I'm open for suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently this was an issue with [sbt-heroku](https://github.com/heroku/sbt-heroku) that we're using, it was fixed in latest version 0.5.4 so with_jmap just works as expected on the play sh script